# Java: Using a mutator method on element of array with a for loop, not working

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, nullpointerexception

This assignment tasks us to create an array for a 'hotel' with various room objects, and these rooms would have elements of room number and cost.

I'm trying to start off by generating this 2D array, then using a for loop which uses a mutator method to set each 'room number' of the array. The code compiles, but I get a nullpointerexception error.

I think once I understand why my methods won't work on the elements, I should be okay. The rest is just scanner input and some exception handling (invalid input  i can just use the throws ioexception thing, right?)

Thank you!

Here is the code:

```
public class Hotel{

   public static void main(String[] args){
  int choice = 0;

  System.out.println("Welcome to the Hotel California.");
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  Room[][] hotel = new Room[8][20];         
  for(int i = 0; i< hotel.length; i++){
     for(int j = 0; j<hotel[i].length;j++){

     int roomNum = (i * 100) + j + 1;

     hotel[i][j].setRoom(roomNum);

     }
  }

  System.out.println(hotel[0][0].getRoomNumber());


     do{

       System.out.println("What business have you today?");
       System.out.println("1. Guest Registration");
       System.out.println("2. Guest Checkout");
       System.out.println("3. Show me occupied rooms");
       System.out.println("4. Exit");

       choice = sc.nextInt();



     }while(choice != 4);


  }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elements in an `Object` array are `null` by default. Initialize the elements within the array itself prior to attempting to invoke any methods on them

```
for (int i = 0; i < hotel.length; i++) {
   for (int j = 0; j < hotel[i].length; j++) {
      hotel[i][j] = new Room();
      ...
   }
}
```

Comment: Oh my god, thank you so much. I thought initializing it was enough, as a Room array would just be all the default values I have for the room.

Sorry, just to avoid spamming more questions, how do I put a try-catch in the "interface" area if you will, without going into an infinite loop? @Reimeus

Comment: Its unclear what you mean there but probably better post as a separate question and clarify there....:)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Hotel{

   public static void main(String[] args){
  int choice = 0;

  System.out.println("Welcome to the Hotel California.");
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  Room[][] hotel = new Room[8][20];         
  for(int i = 0; i< hotel.length; i++){
     for(int j = 0; j<hotel[i].length;j++){

     int roomNum = (i * 100) + j + 1;
     //hotel[i][j] is not initialized yet
     hotel[i][j] = new Room();
     //hotel[i][j] is initialized
     hotel[i][j].setRoom(roomNum);

     }
  }

  System.out.println(hotel[0][0].getRoomNumber());


     do{

       System.out.println("What business have you today?");
       System.out.println("1. Guest Registration");
       System.out.println("2. Guest Checkout");
       System.out.println("3. Show me occupied rooms");
       System.out.println("4. Exit");

       choice = sc.nextInt();



     }while(choice != 4);


  }

}
```

I have made a correction in your code. If the constructor of `Room` expects parameters, then add them to the constructor call. `hotel[i][j]` is not initialized, so you cannot reference to the `setRoom` method of `hotel[i][j].`